# incr operation for a key of memcache is getting reset in every hour

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, caching, memcached

I'm using memcache in gae from app engine api, it's documentation doesn't give any info for setting expiry time, but it's getting reset in every hour. 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.api.memcache.html#google.appengine.api.memcache.Client.incr

```
from google.appengine.api import memcache
def count(key):
    newVal = memcache.incr(key,delta=1,initial_value=1)
    return newVal
```

I want the value to persist for 2 days, How can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 1):

Memcached is an in memory cache. You can never be certain that an object in cache will remain in cache.

There are many reasons why this could happen.

- One your cache is full and someone tries to insert an object, memcache will evict the one that is least used
- There is a concept of slabs in memcache where similar sized object are kept in one slab. It can be that your cache is not full but your slab is and that is evicting the object. You can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/@SkyscannerEng/journey-to-the-centre-of-memcached-b239076e678a#:~:text=Slabs,slab%20have%20a%20similar%20size.)
- One more reason could be that in newer versions of memcache (I think after 1.5.0) memcache has started to evict slabs when they are not used for a long time and a new slab requires space.

The bottom line is that you should not rely on memcached to store your data. Its best to have a source of your data as some database and use memcached as cache only.

Hope this helps